# Как передать в тег img размер миниатюры?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, подскажите можно ли передать тегу img src маленького изображения, я использую стандартную галерею wordpress и прохожу по массиву
вынимаю src для тега а и img, если я в галереи ставлю размер миниатюра естественно выводятся все фото обрезанные по размерам миниатюры так как в функции стоит вывод $src следовательно этот-же путь передается в ссылку, получается что я открываю маленькое изображение, могу ли я передать в src размер миниатюры в href полный размер?

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );


        foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : ?>

         <a class="gallery__item f__col" href="<?php echo $src; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="gallery__item__img" alt="Gallery image" />
         </a>
            <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
endwhile;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
    $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

    $ids = explode(',', $gallery['ids']);
    foreach($ids as $id): 
    $link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id, 'full' );
    $src = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id, 'thumbnail' );
    ?>
        <a class="gallery__item f__col" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="gallery__item__img" alt="Gallery image" />
        </a>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

endwhile;

Comment: Xмм... не отрабатывает почему-то, пустой src и href.

Comment: Проверь что получается в переменной $ids, там по идее должен быть массив с ID изображений галереи. Если там нет массива, то посмотри что в $gallery['ids'], там должны быть ID через запятую указаны.